# Bash script running other bash scripts with user input

Tags: bash, shell

Let's say I have a bash script which relies on user input (using `read` and the like).

I now want to run this script N times, each invocation taking an argument, and where those arguments are read from a text file. So essentially I want to do "for each line in text file call script with line as argument and let the user interact with it".

However, when I call my script through my "forall" loop, my `read` calls are just skipped, no user input is read.

Dumbed down example:

**hello.sh:**

```
name=$1
read -p "How old are you, $name? " age

echo "Hello $name, you are $age years old"
```

This works fine to call as

```
$ ./hello.sh Adam
How old are you, Adam? <user enters 42>
Hello Adam, you are 42 years old
```

Now I create my file of names:

**names.txt:**

```
Andrew
Benjamin
Charles
David
Edward
```

And my `forall` script:

**forall.sh:**

```
file=$1
command=$2

while read line; do
    if [ ! -z "$line" ]; then
        $command $line
    fi
done < $file
```

I now do `forall.sh names.txt ./hello.sh`, expecting to have my 5 users enter their ages, but instead I get this:

```
$ forall.sh names.txt ./hello.sh
Hello Andrew, you are Benjamin years old
Hello Charles, you are David years old
Hello Edward, you are  years old
```

Apparently, the `read` call will consume a line from the `names.txt` file instead of reading from a prompt.

How can I do "for each line in file call script with line" and still have the called script accept user input?

Comment: A much better design is to avoid `read` in the subprocess. Many scripts which require interactive I/O also offer the possibility to instead pass the required parameters as command-line options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stdin` is not the terminal in that loop, it's set to `< $file`. You need to pass the terminal explicitly to that command as stdin:

```
while read -r line; do
    if [ ! -z "$line" ]; then
        $command "$line" < /dev/tty
    fi
done < "$file"
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternately the while-read loop can use a different file descriptor (not stdin)

```sh
# ..............vvv
while read line <&3; do
    [ -n "$line" ] && "$command" "$line"
done 3< "$file"
# ...^^
```